# How would you implement an 1. asynchronous event queue that 2. has event coalescing capabilities

Tags: javascript, web-applications, asynchronous

Setting:

let's say three events happen in three separate part of some application, the event should be handled by two controllers. The application dispatcher is responsible for sending/receiving events from all parts of the application, and this dispatcher should have an asynchronous event queue.

In some cases, two the of three events are related along some attribute but are not of the same name, and only one should be passed to the controller, the other one may be discarded.

Problem:

Currently, I have a 'queue' that really just bounces the event to the controller, this is unhelpful  because I have no way of comparing two events in the queue if only one is ever there at time.

So how do I ensure the events should stay in the queue for a while? I suppose a timeout function could do the trick but is there a better way?

To give credit where it's due, the idea of coalescing events is inspired by Cocoa and I'm basically trying to do something similar.

Comment: I would consider using a global variable to store an array of events.  you could also use the array (or separate variable) to emulate semaphores by storing the status.

Comment: right now the 'queue' is an array that is storing all the events, I guess my main problem is that there needs to be a mechanism that holds events in the array long enough so they may be evaluated. but still clear in a timely manner...

Comment: if they cant be processed immediately, thats when the idea of semaphores comes in, rather than just storing the event also set a "blocked" flag that will get unblocked when the resource you need is free, so your special event handler can iterate over the array and process only the unblocked events, rinse and repeat until they all become unblocked and handled (the blocked flag could be something like var jqueryLoaded=false which could get set to true by adding an onload="jqueryLoaded=true" to the script tag ... similar for other resources, not just js libraries)

Comment: That's really cool and though I've heard of Semaphores before I have never used it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about Cocoa, but I assume that it replaces older events with the latest event until the event is able to be dispatched to the application (i.e. if the application is busy for some reason). I'm not sure what your particular use case is, but if you want to rate-limit the events, I would use `setTimeout` like this:

```
function Dispatcher(controllers) {
    this.controllers = controllers;
    this.events = [];
    this.nextController = 0;
}
Dispatcher.prototype = {
    _dispatch: function (i) {
        var ev = this.events.splice(i, 1);
        this.controllers[this.nextController].handle(ev);
        this.nextController = (this.nextController + 1) % this.controllers.length;
    },
    notify: function (ev) {
        var index = -1, self = this, replace;

        function similer(e, i) {
            if (e.type === ev.type) {
                index = i;
                return true;
            }
        }

        replace = this.events.some(similar);
        if (replace) {
            this.events[i] = ev;
        } else {
            // it's unique
            index = this.events.push(ev) - 1;
            setTimeout(function () {
                self._dispatch(index);
            }, 100);
        }
    }
};
```

Just call `notify` with the event (make sure there's a `type` property or similar) and it will handle the magic. Different types of events will be handled uniquely with their own `setTimeout`.

I haven't tested this code, so there are probably bugs.

Answer (score 1):

> I suppose a timeout function could do the trick but is there a better way?

No, there really isn't.

Usually the way to go is using `setTimeout(..., 0)` if your events are dispatched in the same run loop. So the implementation would look something like this:

```
var eventQueue = [];
var handlerTimer = -1;
function fireEvent(event, params) {
    eventQueue.push([event, params]);
    window.clearTimeout(handlerTimer);
    handlerTimer = window.setTimeout(resolveQueue, 0);
}

function resolveQueue() {
    // process eventQueue and remove unwanted events...
    // then dispatch remaining events

    eventQueue = [];
}
```

If you need to handle events from different run loops (for example native events like `mouseup` and `click`), you need to use some timeout value other than 0. The exact value depends on how long you want to accumulate events.

Comment: Thanks for the additional resource!